# bash script - kill all same processes instead of this one

Tags: bash, csh, tcsh

I have a (bash or csh) script run by the user manually... called myScript.sh

I want to check if there are other instances of this script running and kill them, then start doing its work.

I tried:

```
ps -ef | grep "myScript.sh" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

But it also finds itself and kills everything else and then commits suicide!!!

Any smart quick way to just kill the rest? (without having to do it on another wrapper script) ??

Comment: You can kill processes by name using the command `killall`

Comment: `pkill -f myScript.sh` ? Note: [use of `kill -9` is discouraged](http://turnoff.us/geek/dont-sigkill), unless that is the only way (google for "useless use of kill 9" for details).

Comment: @anishsane But even with pkill ... won't that have the same effect? myScript.sh will kill all the processes called myScript.sh ...so it will commit suicide!!

Comment: Instead of this wouldn't be better to use some kind of watchdog before you start your `myScript.sh`? Why are you face with this problem?

Comment: One working solution would be adding `grep -v $$` between `awk` and `xargs` but that would not be elegant.

Comment: You could add `| grep -v "$$"` before awk

Answer (score 2):

The shortest thing you can do is the following

```
kill $(pgrep -x myScript.sh | grep -v ^$$$)
```

Note that when your PID is `303` an the list is `303 1012 13032 3039`, you have to match the full pid, in order not to exclude `13032` or `3039`.

Answer (score 1):

Filter the process ID of the current invocation from the list passed to `xargs`:

```
me=$$
ps -ef | grep '[m]yScript.sh' | awk -v me=$me '$2 != me {print $2}' | xargs kill
```

A better idea, though, is to simply prevent `myScript.sh` from continuing if it detects another instance of itself running when it starts. Add something like this to the beginning of your script:

```
alreadyrunning=/tmp/foo
if [[ -f $alreadyrunning ]]; then
    exit
else
    trap "rm $alreadyrunning" EXIT
    touch "$alreadyrunning"
    chmod +644 "$alreadyrunning"
fi
```

It's not foolproof (there is a race condition if two instances of your script start at nearly the same time), but in general, it only allows the script to proceed if no other instance has already created `$alreadyrunning`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how do you start you script it might be necessary to add `-f` flag to `pgrep`:

```
pgrep "myScript.sh" | grep -v "$$" | xargs kill -9
```